# Read and output sentences (with spacing between words) in AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to load sentences from a text file into variables, and then output them (In a browser window, for example).

My problem is that after loading the sentence (paragraph) into a variable, it is outputted without spaces between the word.

Ex. "Hello how are you?" loaded into a variable, and then typed using keystroke would appear as "Hellohowareyou?"

```
set theData to "/Users/User/Desktop/theData.txt" 
set theText to read theData 
set EventDescription to paragraph 1 of theText as text

tell application "System Events"    
 tell process "Safari"      
  keystroke EventDescription as text    
 end tell 
end tell
```

edit: If I set the clipboard to the variable "EventDescription" and then paste it, the whitespace is preserved. Only when using "keystroke" is it not.

Comment: What element is receiving the keystrokes? The text is definitely _read_ with the spaces. Also, unless Safari is already frontmost before your script runs, you may end up pasting into a different application.

Comment: So are you trying to make a script that reads a text file containing a Text and search it with safari??

Comment: I am trying to read a text file containing a sentence, store that sentence in a variable, and paste (type) the sentence into a form on a website.

The output is going where I need it to, right into the form, but I noticed that wherever I keystroke the text in Safari (be it the search bar or a form), it is done so without non-breaking spaces between words.

Comment: ok. hmmm sorry but I don't think I know how to fix that